# Reading the ID from a file and auto increment it by 1

Tags: c#

Currently I'm working on this:

I have a windows form with a text file. I use StreamReader with a while loop in order to read the file line by line and then to display it in a listview but then I don't know how to auto-increment the ID in the text box by one so for example if the last id of a person was 1005, the code should automatically add 1 so i'll get 1006

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("INCIDENT.txt"))
{
    int iCount = 0;

    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
    {
        ListViewItem lvRead = new ListViewItem();
        lvRead.Text = sr.ReadLine();
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lstViewData.Items.Add(lvRead);

        iCount++; 
    }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaWQt.png)

Comment: Just FYI, you don't necessarily need to keep `peek`ing. `ReadLine()` returns null if there is no more.

Comment: can you help me with the other bit, how to i make it read the last ID and then increment it by 1?

Comment: for this we need to know how the string looks

Comment: Have you tried anything to change the textbox's value? It is *almost* as straightforward as initially setting it. It's not super clear what you're stuck on.

Comment: Show the code for how you're setting the textbox value

Comment: Just in case you're using this for a database ID - dont do that. The DB will do it for you.

Comment: you can see the image that shows how the text box is used. so let me rephprase it again. I have a text file that has this layout
1002
wwww
Staff
dasda
dsawawz
No
zzzzz
Yes
I read this file and I want to autoincrement the last ID by 1 to the text box in the image attached

Comment: There's no database included in this :)

Comment: @AlexT we see the image but the question still remains: What *exactly* are you stuck on? Have you tried incrementing that value yourself yet? Changing the value of a `TextBox` is not at all difficult.

Answer (score 0):

try code after edit you should after opening any stream close it

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have a button and it's name SaveData and you saved nom.1 in your TextFile

```
private void btnSaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     StreamReader sr =  new 
     StreamReader("INCIDENT.txt"); 
     int num = sr.Peek();
     sr.Close();
     // here will assign last value in num
     txtID.Text = ( num + 1 ).ToString();
     // here add 1 to num and display result in textBox and you should save last value to use it later
     StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("INCIDENT.txt");
     sw.Write( ( num + 1 ).ToString() );
     // here save last value you get to increment this value when you read TextFile again
     sw.Fush();
     sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: I tried this one but when I try to run it it gives me an error. System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'D:\Scoala\PROFESSIONAL PRACTICE WEEK\Fourth\Alex Todea-Task1-PPW4\Alex Todea-Task1-PPW4\bin\Debug\INCIDENT.txt' because it is being used by another process.'